# Is it possible to apply a prediction on a data set with less features

Tags: data-analysis, data-science, bigdata

Let assume I have a data structured as follows:

**ID, Feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, outcome**

The  historical data is present for all features.

but the prediction need to be done at a stage where only **ID, Feature 1, feature 2** are available.

how can we build a kind of prediction (predict the outcome) by taking advantage of feature 3 from historical data?

Is this assumption correct? or is there any strategies to be adopted.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sufficient data, try comparing a model on all 3 features vs only 1 & 2 by predicting entirely within that set (using train, test, score per example). From there you could see where -- and how -- the 3rd feature gives you an edge. You could then use that information to calibrate the 2-features predictor and apply it to the actual scoring set.

Comment: Thank you @dominic111 for your answer, but in case feature3 has a value in prediction what to do in this case when applying the prediction with only feature 1 & 2? is there a way to engineer feature 3 in order to inject its transformation permanently?

Comment: You could use the other variables to predict it could give you insights on how your 2 other features might produce errors. To be clear, I think that in the vast majority of cases, it would be hard to interpret, but if you want to try it, you could maybe find some insights on the error patterns.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of the error patterns, I am new to DS field and need more insights. thanks